# TurboRepo, run only some workspaces

Tags: next.js, turborepo

this is my structure of workspaces:

- apps

  - web-1 (next)
  - web-2 (next)
  - web-3 (next)
- packages

  - pack-1 (ui)
  - pack-2  (react utils)
  - pack-3 (node utils)
- services

  - service-1 (express)
  - service-2 (express)
  - service-3 (express)
  - service-4 (express)

I want to be able to run "run dev:web-1" , or "run dev:web-2" or "run dev:web-3"
in which
always ALL the packages are available
one or 2 of the services are included

If I run "yarn dev" right now, everything fires up and i actually had to set the --concurrency to a higher value and i don't want to be doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so after a longer look into the documentation, i found the `--filter flag` can be set several times on the `turbo run` command. So, my solution was to add scripts to my main `package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "turbo run build",
    "dev": "turbo run dev",
    "lint": "turbo run lint",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{ts,tsx,md}\"",
    "dev:web-1": "turbo run dev --filter=web-1 --filter=service-2 --filter=service-3",
    "dev:screen": "turbo run dev --filter=web-2 --filter=service-1"
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

TurboRepo now provides the option to run a specific workspace with all of its dependencies. In your case, it would be:
`turbo dev --filter=web-1...` or change `web-1` for any other application you want to start.

Reference: https://turbo.build/repo/docs/core-concepts/monorepos/filtering#include-dependencies-of-matched-workspaces

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired behavior of running specific development scripts for web applications while ensuring that all packages are available and one or two services are included, you can use **Yarn** workspaces and a script management tool like **npm-run-all** or concurrently.

To do that you need to install the necessary dependencies:

```bash
yarn add -D npm-run-all
```

> > Update your **package.json** file in the root directory to include the dev scripts:

json

```json
"scripts": {
  "dev:web-1": "cd apps/web-1 && yarn dev",
  "dev:web-2": "cd apps/web-2 && yarn dev",
  "dev:web-3": "cd apps/web-3 && yarn dev",
  "dev:services": "run-p dev:service-1 dev:service-2",
  "dev:service-1": "cd services/service-1 && yarn dev",
  "dev:service-2": "cd services/service-2 && yarn dev",
  "dev:all": "run-p dev:packages dev:web-1 dev:web-2 dev:web-3 dev:services",
  "dev:packages": "yarn workspace pack-1 dev && yarn workspace pack-2 dev && yarn workspace pack-3 dev"
}
```

In the respective apps/web-X and services/service-X directories, ensure that the yarn dev scripts are properly defined in their respective package.json files.

Now you can run the following commands:

> yarn dev:web-1 to start the development server for web-1.

> yarn dev:web-2 to start the development server for web-2.

> yarn dev:web-3 to start the development server for web-3.

> yarn dev:services to start the development servers for service-1 and service-2.

> yarn dev:all to start all development servers, including the web applications and selected services.

By separating the specific development scripts for each web application and services, and using a script management tool like **npm-run-all** or concurrently, you can control the concurrency of running the different services and ensure that all the required packages are available.

Remember to update the scripts and file paths according to your specific project structure and configurations.

Comment: Thank you. I like this, and will use it in case i can't find what i'm looking for but i'm sure there must be a turborepo specific solution for this.

Comment: You're welcome, yes provably, I also didn't find it, sorry for not be able to help more.

Comment: I posted my own answer with the solution i found from digging into the docs, if you're interested